# nested loop in django template is not showing correct output

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to print brand and it's links and I am using nested loops but it is not showing correct output

here is my code

```
{% for brand_report in brand_reports %}
  <h1> REPORT for Brand: {{ brand_report.brand.name }}</h1>
  {% for link in brand_report.links.all %}
    <h3>link:</h3><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{link.url}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Desired output is

```
REPORT for Brand: SizCom
link:
https://www.justdial.com/Kozhikode/SizCom-Near-to-Big-Bazaar-Calicut-City/0495PX495-X495-151217184614-Z4I2_BZDET
REPORT for Brand: SizCom
link:
https://www.justdial.com/Kozhikode/SizCom-Near-to-Big-Bazaar-Calicut-City/0495PX495-X495-151217184614-Z4I2_BZDET
```

But i am getting output like this

```
REPORT for Brand: SizCom
REPORT for Brand: SizCom
link:
https://www.justdial.com/Kozhikode/SizCom-Near-to-Big-Bazaar-Calicut-City/0495PX495-X495-151217184614-Z4I2_BZDET
link:
https://www.justdial.com/Kozhikode/SizCom-Near-to-Big-Bazaar-Calicut-City/0495PX495-X495-151217184614-Z4I2_BZDET
```

Don't know what i am doing wrong

model:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
"""For the brand"""

name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
context = models.ManyToManyField(Context, blank=True)
variation = models.ManyToManyField('BrandVariation', blank=True, related_name='brand')
status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class ResultLink(models.Model):
    """for results"""
    url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, null=True)
    parent_site = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(BrandVariation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='link')
   date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self):
     return "%s" % self.url

class BrandReport(TimeStampedModel):
""""""
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, related_name='counterfeit_report')
links = models.ManyToManyField(ResultLink, blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Brand Report"
```

Views :

```
def view(request,brands):
  template_path = 'profile_brand_report.html'
  brand_reports = BrandReport.objects.filter(brand__id__in=brands)
  context = {'brand_reports': brand_reports}
  html = render_to_string(template_path, context)
```

Comment: Can you provide the models file so I can check the relations?

Comment: @MiniGunnR models provided

Comment: Can you show your views.py?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your project. The only thing you missed providing was your view. So I suppose that is where your problem is. Here is my view:

```
def demoview(request):
    objs = BrandReport.objects.all()
    c = {
        "brand_reports": objs,
    }
    return render(request, "blog/demoview.html", c)
```

And here is my template:

```
{% for brand_report in brand_reports %}
  <h1> REPORT for Brand: {{ brand_report.brand.name }}</h1>
  {% for link in brand_report.links.all %}
    <h3>link:</h3><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{link.url}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And my result is exactly how you have desired. Please check your view.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have a first BrandReport without any related link and a second BrandReport with two related links - check your database.

FWIW, I actually don't get what your BrandReport model is since you already have a foreignkey to Brand in ResultLink. Your BrandReport model is not only redundant (as far as we can tell) but also brittle since it allows to relate any ReportLink to any Brand without respecting the `ReportLink.brand` constraint.